# Pasar id a pagina sin sesiones

Tags: jquery

Estoy haciendo un modulo de venta y con un boton voy a la lista de clientes. al hace click en una fila de la tabla quiero en la peticion AJAX llamar a l index y pasar el idcliente como parametro para consultarlo en el ready.
Porque no quiero usar sesiones porque no es un carrito de ventas, es una venta espontanea en un local.

```js
$('#clientes tbody').on('click','tr', function(evt){
    
       $(this).find('input:radio').prop('checked', true);
 var idc= $('input:radio[name=seleccion]:checked').attr("id");
alert(idc);
    var accion = 'asociar';
    $.ajax({
   
            type: "POST",
  
            data: {"idc":idc,"accion":accion}, 
            

            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
           success: function(data){
          
            window.location.href ="index.php?controller=venta&action=index?id=".idc;
           }
           
        });
}); });
```

Uso el modelo vista controlador. si paso un n umero fijo dentro del string funciona perfecto..pero con la variable no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema veo que está en como construís la URL, antes de id deberías poner un &, además la concatenación en JavaScript deberías hacerla con un +, o sea, debería ser así:

```
$('#clientes tbody').on('click','tr', function(evt){

       $(this).find('input:radio').prop('checked', true);
 var idc= $('input:radio[name=seleccion]:checked').attr("id");
alert(idc);
    var accion = 'asociar';
    $.ajax({

            type: "POST",

            data: {"idc":idc,"accion":accion}, 


            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
           success: function(data){

            window.location.href ="index.php?controller=venta&action=index&id=" + idc;
           }

        });
}); });
```

De todas formas, no se si lo mejor es pasarle el ID por la URL, porque cualquier usuario podría cambiarlo.

Espero te sirva.

¡Suerte!

Comment: Funciono..pero no se como tomar ese id en la ventana de venta, osea en el js del index.vos decis que conviene una sesion?

Comment: Yo creo que si conviene utilizar sesión para mantener el id del usuario, así no lo puede cambiar a mano.  Si de todas formas quieres hacerlo en JavaScript, acá hay un ejemplo de cómo leer las variables de la URL desde JS: https://gomakethings.com/getting-all-query-string-values-from-a-url-with-vanilla-js/.

Comment: Gracias amigo!!!